# Sum in array with for loop in C language

Tags: c, for-loop

I want to sum this array from `b[0]` until `b[42]`, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me please? this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int b[43] = { 327, 351, 86, 24, 812, 347, 813, 1155, 1049, 378, 370, 837, 1051, 455, 1153, 470, 265, 156, 718, 1284, 1094, 1052, 1204, 116, 1182, 40, 920, 281, 475, 993, 782, 1053, 17, 332, 846, 1021, 379, 121, 157, 96, 663, 175, 1061 };
    int i;
    int sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 43; ++i) {
        sum += b[i];
    }
    printf("%d", &sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sum` and not `&sum` in the `printf`

Comment: `printf("%d", &sum);` -> `printf("%d", sum);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in `printf("%d", &sum)` you shouldn't be using `&` sign. Replacing it with `printf("%d", sum)` should work. Check out the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) for usage/